# Shiny save user input to google sheets

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a personality survey and am trying to save the data to google sheets.

I started by creating a sheet with a first row of zero and the headers I want. I have code to display the scores of participants in output$vaules. I tried to use that to save to the google sheet but that also did not work.

I am not getting any errors but the data is not being saved to the google sheet I initialized.

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)
shiny_token <- gs_auth() 
saveRDS(shiny_token, "shiny_app_token.rds")


initial_sheet <- data.frame(open1 = 0, open2 = 0,  consc1 = 
0, consc2 = 0, extra1 = 0, extra2 = 0, agree1 = 0, agree2 = 
0, neur1 = 0, neur2 = 0)


gdoc_name <- "big5"
ss <- gs_new(gdoc_name, input=initial_sheet)
sheetkey <- ss$sheet_key


sheetkey <- "xxxx" #actual key would be here
ss <- gs_key(sheetkey)

set.seed(3000)
xseq<-seq(1,7,.01)
densities <-dnorm(xseq, 4,1)
```

## ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
table <- "responses",
titlePanel("Personality Traits"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

sliderInput("extra1", "I see myself as someone who is extraverted, enthusiastic.", min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("agree1", "I see myself as someone who is critical, quarrelsome.",min = 1, max = 7,value = 1),

sliderInput("consc1", "I see myself as someone who is dependable, self-disciplined.",min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("neur1", "I see myself as someone who is anxious, easily upset.",min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("open1", "I see myself as someone who is open to new experiences, complex.", min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("extra2", "I see myself as someone who is reserved, quiet.", min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("agree2", "I see myself as someone who is sympathetic, warm.", min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("consc2", "I see myself as someone who is disorganized, careless", min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("neur2", "I see myself as someone who is calm, emotionally stable.",  min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

sliderInput("open2", "I see myself as someone who is conventional, uncreative.", min = 1, max = 7, value = 1),

actionButton("submit", "Submit")
),
mainPanel(
tableOutput("values")
))
)
```

## server

```
server <- function(input, output) {
sliderValues <- reactive({
data.frame(Name = c("Openness","Conscientiousness","Extraversion", "Agreeableness", "Neuroticism"),
Value = as.character(c((input$open1 + (8-input$open2))/2 (input$consc1 + (8 - input$consc2))/2, (input$extra1 + (8 - input$extra2))/2,(input$agree2 + (8 - input$agree1))/2,(input$neur1 + (8 - input$neur2))/2)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})

observeEvent(input$submit, {
output$values <- renderTable({
sliderValues()
})

observeEvent(input$save, {
open1 <- input$open1
open2 <- input$open2
consc1 <- input$consc1
consc2 <- input$consc2
extra1 <- input$extra1
extra2 <- input$extra2
agree1 <- input$agree1
agree2 <- input$agree2
neur1 <- input$neur1
neur2 <- input$neur1
gs_add_row(input = output$save)
})
}
```

## run app

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I am trying something similar. I am using this command: gs_add_row(gsheet, ws = 'name', input = data, verbose = TRUE) to add a value to each cell. I am not getting anywhere. If someone has an answer it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After making my comment early today, I played with my code and got it to update my google sheet.

In my project, I want to click payment and send the payment date to the paid column (C5) in my datasheet. This needs to be performed as many times as empty cells (Not paid) are there (therefore the 'for' loop).

I count all the rows in my spreadsheet (total_rows) and the number of rows without a date in the paid column (n_rows). These values provided me with the range of empty cells the code needs to update after the action button is activated.

This is added to the UI portion of the app:

```
actionButton("payments", label = "EXECUTE PAYMENTS")
```

This to the server:

```
sheet = function() {gs_title("Title of the googlesheet")}
historic = function(){ sheet() %>% gs_read(ws = "spreadsheet name")}

observeEvent(input$payments, {
    total_rows = nrow(historic())
    ndata = historic() %>% filter(is.na(paid))
    n_rows = nrow(ndata)
    if (total_rows == n_rows){n_rows = n_rows+1}
    for (i in (total_rows - n_rows + 2) : (total_rows+1)) {
       anchor_range = paste("R", i, "C5", sep = "", collapse = NULL)
       sheet() %>% gs_edit_cells(ws = "spreadsheet name", input = Sys.Date(), anchor = anchor_range)
  }
```

Hope this works for you. 
J